# Perspective Puzzlery! Determine Distance and Angle of View Point, from a Rectangle, in a Digital Image.

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

Given points; A - (341, 81)   B - (265, 630)   C - (884, 459)   D - (896, 942)
represent the coordinates of the corners of a rectangle in a digital photo.

The true distance of Line AB=CD is 24 inches and Line AC=BD is 18 inches.

How do you calculate the distance and angle of the "Camera" to the center of the rectangle. Would the answer be a vector?

Humans are weird, we can look at the image and solve it mentally, understanding the position of the camera... but how can you actually calculate such an answer.

[image]

Comment: This doesn’t really have anything to do with calculus.

Comment: My friend said that he had a similar problem to this in calc 3.

Comment: Putting further though into it, and thinking about how lens work... It seems to be non euclidean.

Comment: You should give the conversion factor between inches and the coordinates units, i.e. how many pixels in an inch.

Comment: Are you sure your data are correct? I tried to reproduce the perspective but it wasn't possible.

Comment: I think you exchanged $B$ and $C$ coordinates.

Comment: Even exchanging $B$ with $C$, however, I cannot reproduce the original rectangle correctly: when the ratio of its sides is $4:3$ the angle between them is about 60° and not 90° as it should be.